# How to make all data points the same color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm hoping this will be a simple solution, but how do I assign a single color to every data point in my bubble chart?  When I specify `color=` or `fill=`, despite my color specification (ex: `color = "blue"`) it only ever comes out red.

I even added a new column in the data frame where all rows have the same categorical value "samecolor", which I assign as `fill = samecolor` and specify later using `scale_color_manual(values = c('mediumorchid')`.

I have my full code here:

```
p.class <- ggplot(data_melt, aes(x=pond, y=variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value, fill = samecolor), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("mediumorchid")) +
  #scale_fill_discrete(values = c("mediumorchid")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.direction = "horizontal",
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Taxonomy (Class)") +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text( size = 15, face = "bold"))
```

where I have commented out `scale_fill_discrete()`, for that was for a trial run with `fill = samecolor`.

Thank you in advance!

For reproducibility, here is my dput() output of a toy data set:

```
> dput(data_melt)
structure(list(pond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("GG", "LG", "SM"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = c("taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", 
    "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", "taxa1", 
    "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", 
    "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa2", "taxa3", "taxa3", 
    "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", 
    "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa3", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", 
    "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", "taxa4", 
    "taxa4", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", 
    "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5", "taxa5"), value = c(0.134328358208955, 
    0.00497512437810945, 0.00746268656716418, 0.0124378109452736, 
    0.054726368159204, 0.203980099502488, 0.114427860696517, 
    0.109452736318408, 0.154228855721393, 0.00746268656716418, 
    0.00497512437810945, 0.191542288557214, 0.0757575757575758, 
    0.0833333333333333, 0.113636363636364, 0.128787878787879, 
    0.0606060606060606, 0.0227272727272727, 0.121212121212121, 
    0.0303030303030303, 0.0303030303030303, 0.143939393939394, 
    0.159090909090909, 0.0303030303030303, 0.0797498045347928, 
    0.0867865519937451, 0.0781860828772478, 0.0766223612197029, 
    0.0750586395621579, 0.0594214229867084, 0.0969507427677873, 
    0.0953870211102424, 0.101641907740422, 0.0836591086786552, 
    0.0852228303362002, 0.0813135261923378, 0.0163934426229508, 
    0.0655737704918033, 0.0327868852459016, 0.0819672131147541, 
    0.0491803278688525, 0.114754098360656, 0.0983606557377049, 
    0.131147540983607, 0.147540983606557, 0.0819672131147541, 
    0.131147540983607, 0.0491803278688525, 0.088339222614841, 
    0.0918727915194346, 0.0848056537102474, 0.0812720848056537, 
    0.0989399293286219, 0.0777385159010601, 0.0742049469964664, 
    0.0777385159010601, 0.102473498233216, 0.0918727915194346, 
    0.0671378091872792, 0.0636042402826855), samecolor = c("color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", "color", 
    "color", "color", "color")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you want to set the points all to the same color you most often want to use the aesthetic *outside* `aes()`.  So code like `geom_point(aes(size = value), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21, fill = "mediumorchid")` would do it.  Setting to a constant does not make legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is better to use `scale_fill_manual()` with the desired color if you want to change your `fill` option. You can set any color you wish. Just take into account that `fill` and `color` are different aesthetics elements. That is why you got tomato color in your original color because you were tryning to change `color` when `fill` was turned on. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data_melt, aes(x=pond, y=variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value, fill = samecolor), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue")) +
  #scale_fill_discrete(values = c("blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.direction = "horizontal",
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Taxonomy (Class)") +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text( size = 15, face = "bold"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, Duck.  I really appreciate your help with this question... and basically all my previous questions. Take care!